# Custom 404 error message in Web API responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to modify the message which comes when the Web API throws 404 error:

Right now if any api doesn't exists let's say on accessing https://mywebsite/api/foo/?%22%26gt;%26lt;script%26gt;_q_q=)(%26lt;/script%26gt;

I get the following response:

> { "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'https://mywebsite/api/foo/?\"><script>_q_q=)(</script>'.",
>   "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'MyController' that
>   matches the request." }

I want to modify this message.

In order to do that I tried this..

I added a custom attribute over my controller:

```
[NoActionFoundFilterAttribute]
public class MyController
```

The code of filter is:

```
public class NoActionFoundFilterAttribute: ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // My code
    }
}
```

And in Web API Config I have already added the filter:

```
 config.Filters.Add(new NoActionFoundFilterAttribute());
```

Even after doing all the above steps the OnException 
 method "NoActionFoundFilterAttribute" file is not being hit when invalid action is being called.

Can you share what I am missing in order to modify the custom 404 error message

Comment: I'm not sure if others have arrived here for the same reason. But I found this question as a result of cross site scripting being possible for 'not found' pages. Out of the box, I expected this not to be possible!

Answer (score 15):

I was able to find the solution.

Here is what I did:

I added the following line to hook into Web API response pipeline for the messages returned by Web API:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new WebApiCustomMessageHandler());
```

and then I implemented the WebApiCustomMessageHandler like this:

```
public class WebApiCustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            request.Properties.Remove(HttpPropertyKeys.NoRouteMatched);
            var errorResponse = request.CreateResponse(response.StatusCode, "Content not found.");
            return errorResponse;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

After implementing the above solution I was able to modify the ContentNotFound responses from WebAPI. The response finally came like this:

> "Content not found."

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I found it surprising that an XSS seems feasible with Query parameters for the 404 page. Your answer provides a solution to that.

Comment: Same as @the-senator I was looking for the right place to put this sort if thing bit didn't know the pipeline well enough found the documentation for the DelegatingHandler a good help to understanding this answer.

Comment: @Raghav config.MessageHandlers.Add(new WebApiCustomMessageHandler()); this doesn't work in .NET Core Web API, can you suggest on how to register on .NET Core Web API application please

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for an answer to customize the response message for status code 404 in ASP.NET core/ASP.NET 5. we can create a middleware that is at the end of the pipeline

```cs
public class ResponseMessageMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseMessageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // invoke _next to make the next code run before the response sended
        await _next(httpContext); 
        
        // Make sure the response has not been sent by the controller, 
        // this ensures that the message we are about to send does not 
        // suppress messages from the controller with the same status code
        if (!httpContext.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            switch (httpContext.Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 404:
                    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new
                    {
                        Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
                        Title = "Notfound.",
                        Status = 404
                    });

                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because we must put the middleware on the end of the pipeline and based on this diagram, we must register the middleware in the first order.

[image]

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    // Currently, I don't know what app.UseRouting() does but putting 
    // middleware after app.UseRouting() works
    app.UseMiddleware<ResponseMessageMiddleware>();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

With this code, we don't need to put attributes on every controller or anything else, and this code also works for other status code responses, currently, I use it to handle 401 and 405 response messages.